# Why image doesn't center in <table><td>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

so i am building a web-app with google script and the result is a dashboard with several tables. I am also using bootstrap (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css).
I've been looking for an answer for long days but i just can't find out what i am missing.

So in a table, i want to insert an image that has to be centered horizontally and vertically, in the center of the td and has to fit and adapt to the row or td height i'll choose.

But again and again, my image goes to the bottom of the td/row and often overlaps and below the row, it seems to have the right height, but it never places itself correctly. I have made a copy of little portion of my code to make it clearer:

[Here the result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI6bc.png)

And here is my code:

```css
.row {}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  line-height: 20px;
}

th,
td {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="width: 500px">
      <!-- TABLE TEST -->
      <div>
        <!-- Test -->
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Rank</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td>
              <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
              <td>33</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>111</td>
              <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
              <td>333</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- CLOSE TABLE TEST -->
```

I have tried what i found around: display:block, position:relative for parents, absolute for childs, and several other solutions, but nothing seems to work.
I am clearly missing something and i probably have messed with the styles so much that i even might have tried the good solution which might have been blocked by other mistakes.

Thanks to who might help

Comment: Have you tried examining it in the DOM inspector to see what the bounding box of the image is?

Comment: you need to place the css and html inside a single snippet

Comment: @Barmar ? I am new to html, just learning it right now, i don't know what DOM inspector is, i'll try and look for it, thx.

Comment: It's the Elements tab of Developer Tools in Chrome.

Comment: @fnostro i just made a copy of a portion of the code, i just couldn't paste it all, but other than this very problem, all other styles work fine.

Comment: Here is the complete code above the portion:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
 
        
[portion starts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt: simplify

I've added a border around your td's so you can see the effects

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}

td>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="width: 500px">
  <!-- TABLE TEST -->
  <div>
    <!-- Test -->
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
          <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>111</td>
          <td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td>
          <td>333</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- CLOSE TABLE TEST -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I used your solution because it was the closest to the code i had and it looked easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `width: 100%;` on the image container, `display: flex;` to make it responsive and `justify-content: center;` to center the image.

```css
.row {
  }

  table {
    text-align: center;
  }  

  tr {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  
  th, td {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
  }
  
  .image_container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="width: 500px"> <!-- TABLE TEST -->
        <div > <!-- Test -->
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Rank</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Points</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr><td>1</td><td>
              <div class="image_container">
              <img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></div></td><td>3</td></tr>
              <tr><td>11</td><td>
              <div class="image_container">
              <img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></div></td><td>33</td></tr>
              <tr><td>111</td><td>
              <div class="image_container">
              <img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></div></td><td>333</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div> <!-- CLOSE TABLE TEST -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: thank you, i'll try to understand better your solution and display: flex and might use it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I have added some small changes. Try this part of the code to place instead of your current css:

```
 tr {
    line-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  th, td {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  img {
    height:20px;
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you, as for the comment above, i'll read about display flex to understand how to use it properly!

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
    text-align: center;
  }  
  
  th, td {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-size: 50px
  }

  img {
    display: inline-block; /* display should be inline or inline-block */
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical align should be middle */
    position: relative; /* position should be relative */
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="width: 600px"> <!-- TABLE TEST -->
          <!-- <div> loose open tag here -->
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Rank</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Points</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr><td>1</td><td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td><td>3</td></tr>
              <tr><td>11</td><td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td><td>33</td></tr>
              <tr><td>111</td><td><img src="https://static.sky.it/images/skytg24/it/spettacolo/serie-tv/2021/02/25/spongebob-serie-tv-kamp-koral/kamp.jpg"></td><td>333</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div> <!-- CLOSE TABLE TEST -->
```

Comment: thanks a lot. display: inline-block; and position: relative; are the opposit of a solution i had read online, i'll have to read about it

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, you have to remove 2 styles from  tag in your CSS:

- Display:block
- Position:absolute

  .row {
     }

     table {
       text-align: center;
     }  

     tr {
       line-height: 20px;
     }

     th, td {
       position:relative;
       text-align:center;
       vertical-align:middle;
     }

     img {
       vertical-align: center;
       height:20px;
     }